# Setting Rows in Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

Is there a way to optimize this code or does it have to be listed as I have it below?  This correctly adds fields A & B to my pivot as expected but would prefer rather than repeating each 'With' to have it all nested together so it makes adding more fields easier/more readable.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields("[Field A]")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.LayoutForm = xlTabular
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields("[Field B]")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
.LayoutForm = xlTabular
End With
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a Sub or a Function with a couple parameters then. In this way, you have one section of code, but can change the field name, position (or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the repeated parts into a separate method with the appropriate parameters.

Like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    
    AddPivotField pt, "[FieldA]", xlRowField, 1
    AddPivotField pt, "[FieldB]", xlRowField, 2

End Sub


Sub AddPivotField(pt As PivotTable, cubeField As String, _
            orient As XlPivotFieldOrientation, pos As Long)
    With pt.CubeFields(cubeField)
        .Orientation = orient
        .Position = pos
        .LayoutForm = xlTabular
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for providing example for this.  Very helpful!  Works like a charm and syntax looks much clearer.  Macro runs smoother too!